# Red gate DLM Automation binding error using VSTS

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, redgate

I'm using Red gate DLM Automation version 2 on VSTS. I installed DLM on the build server, it's fully licensed, and I have noth the build and release VSTS plugins installed. But now, when I perform a build on VSTS, I receive the following error message:

**System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'transactionIsolationLevel'. ---> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'transactionIsolationLevel'.**

My initial guess is that I have a version conflict between some Red Gate PowerShell libraries, but I cannot find any further information on this error.The build server is running PowerShell v4. The SQL code being built does not have any references to "transaction isolation" in it, but I don't think that's the problem. I have completed successful builds on this VSTS server in the past and am now confused what caused this error to start appearing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least 2.0.3 of the DLMA install on the local agent to work with the VSTS plugin - we added the Transaction Isolation Level option very recently, and VSTS auto-updates, but the DLMA install doesn't.

Sorry about that - we are looking into better update / communication mechanisms to keep these things in sync in future (or at least tell you what the problem is) but aren't quite there yet.

If you're still having trouble after updating the DLMA install on the local agent, please do get in touch via support@red-gate.com and we'll sort it out for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate it! I will try upgrading DLMA (which I'm guessing I can download with my SQL Toolbelt license) and give it a try.

Comment: Hello - the build now works after upgrading, but my release is giving me an error I have never seen before: "The specified directory contains more than one NuGet package, please specify a single package" - all of the artifacts have multiple nuget files in them, so I don't completely understand this new issue.

Comment: We had some customers having trouble with packages that were constantly incorporating themselves, and so there are some safeguards which may be preventing you from packaging other nuget packages - if you can get in touch with support@red-gate.com we can help work out how we should handle your particular situation.